# Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS not able to boot on a Lenovo X220

Tags: boot, server, 20.04

I'm trying to get a Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS to install on my old Lenovo ThinkPad X220, but i cannot get it to work properly. Boot from the USB stick and installation is going smoothly, and I've attempted to use the default settings, but once the install is finished and the machine reboots nothing boots. I've updated the bios to the newest one for the machine from 2018 (1.46 i believe).

What are my options?

Comment: *"nothing boots"*. Could you explain this with more detail?

Comment: I went into the bios and selected to ONLY boot on first the harddrive and then the usb.. Ofcourse when i remove the USB after the install theres only the Harddrive to boot from. But since the system cannot boot I'm instead presented with a boot screen.

Comment: @DanielJørgensen Any luck?